# Catching an exception when loading a groovy file

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have these 3 groovy files:

A.groovy:

```
// ...
stage("Test")
{
    throw new Exception("This script fails")
}
```

B.groovy:

```
// ...
stage("Test")
{
    // Nothing, want this to pass
}
```

main.groovy:

```
// ...
m = [:]
status = [:]
scripts = ["A", "B"]
for script in scripts
{
    m["${script}"] = 
    {
        stage("${script}")
        {
            try
            {
                 load "${script}.groovy"
                 status["${script}"] = true
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                 status["${script}"] = false   
            }
        }
    }
}

parallel m

for result_iterator in status:
    print "${result_iterator.key} resulted in ${result_iterator.value}"
```

The code above is a sketch of the real code =)
When I run main.groovy to see the results in the status dictionary, I only get to see B. A threw an exception and thus it didn't add itself to the dictionary. Is there a way I can catch A's exception somehow?

Comment: So you mean the exception thrown by "A.groovy" is not catched by the `catch` block?

Comment: Exactly @zett42

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem 1

You got bitten by the way Groovy closures capture variables outside of their scope. The references to `script` inside the closure will receive the value of `script` at the time when the closure is run, which will be the **last value** of `script`. So both closures actually load **"B.groovy"** and the exception is never thrown!

The fix is simple, just create a local variable inside of the loop that captures the current value of `script`:

```groovy
for( script in scripts ) {
    def theScript = script
    // Now only use theScript inside of the closure!
}
```

## Problem 2

You are not serializing write access to the `status` variable from `parallel` threads. This could result in very nasty, hard-to-reproduce bugs.

The fix is to use [`Map.asSynchronized()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Map.html#asSynchronized()) to create a [synchronized map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap-java.util.Map-):

```groovy
status = [:].asSynchronized()
```

## Complete 'main.groovy' fix

```groovy
m = [:]
status = [:].asSynchronized()  // because multiple threads write to this variable
scripts = ["A", "B"]

for( script in scripts ) {
    def theScript = script  // Important to pass the current value into the closure!

    m[ theScript ] = {
        stage( theScript ) {
            try {
                 load "${theScript}.groovy"
                 status[ theScript ] = true
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                 status[ theScript ] = false   
            }
        }
    }
}

parallel m

for( result_iterator in status ) {
    print "${result_iterator.key} resulted in ${result_iterator.value}"
}
```

**Note:** I have also removed the unnecessary string interpolations.

Comment: Amazing! The fixes helped. Thank you! :)