# Check parallel stages status

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I have something like this:

```
stages {
    stage('createTemplate') {
        parallel {
            stage('template_a') {
                creating template a
            }
            stage('template_b') {
                creating template b
            }
        }
    }
    stage('deployVm') {
        parallel {
            stage('deploy_a') {
                deploy vm a
            }
            stage('deploy_b') {
                deploy vm b
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I make sure that deployVm stages run when and only when respective createTemplate stages were successful?

Comment: If one of the `createTemplate` parallel stages were unsuccessful, your pipeline stops and never gets to any of the `deployVm` stages to begin with.

Comment: So how would one implement such a scenario where I want to proceed with "b" part even though "a" part failed?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to run one `parallel` like this:

```
parallel {
  stage('a') { 
    stages { 
      stage ('template_a') { ... } 
      stage ('deploy_a') { ... } 
    }
  stage('b') {
    stages {
      stage ('template_b') { ... }
      stage ('deploy_b') { ... } 
    }
  }
}
```

This will make sure only stages that `deploy` are the ones following successful `template` stages.

Comment: That would be ok for this specific example, but in reality I will have many more further steps that are identical for a and b (and there will be 10+ parallel jobs), how would you avoid duplicating same code in that case?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/60683176/2047614 for scripting the creation of parallel steps.