# How can I have one pipeline executed even if the other has failed in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the following (part of a) pipeline

```
stages {
    stage('bootstrap') {
        parallel {
            stage("Linux") {
                agent { label 'linux' }
                steps {
                    sh 'bootstrap.sh'
                }   
            }   
            stage("Windows") {
                agent { label 'Windows' }
                steps {
                    bat 'bootstrap.bat'
                }   
            }   
        }   
    }   

    stage('devenv') {
        parallel {
            stage('Linux') {
                agent { label 'linux' }
                steps {
                    sh 'devenv.sh'
                }   
            }   
            stage('Windows') {
                agent { label 'Windows' }
                steps {
                    bat 'devenv.bat'
                }   
            }   
        }   
    }     
}   
post {
    always {
        echo "Done"
    }   
}
```

The problem is that when bootstrap.bat fails on windows, the devenv step is now considered failed, and the linux devenv won't continue. I would like to have the results of the linux pipeline even if the windows one fails early.

An option would be to separate the stages so that linux full pipeline is on one branch of the parallel execution, and windows is on the other, but maybe there's a trick I am not aware of, because I tried it and it does not seem to be acceptable syntax.

### Edit

Suggested fix does not work. This is the pipeline

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    parallel {
        stage('Linux') {
            agent { label 'linux' }
            stages {
                stage('bootstrap') {
                    sh "ls"
                }
                stage('devenv') {
                    sh "ls"
                }
            }
        }
        stage('windows') {
            agent { label 'Windows' }
            stages {
                stage('bootstrap') {
                    bat 'dir'
                }
                stage('devenv') {
                    bat 'dir'
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is the error message

```
WorkflowScript: 8: Undefined section "parallel" @ line 8, column 5.
       parallel {
       ^

WorkflowScript: 1: Missing required section "stages" @ line 1, column 1.
   pipeline {
   ^
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60762090/2047614

Comment: @MaratC can you put a parallel directive under pipeline?

Comment: @MaratC doesn't work. see edit

Comment: `parallel` needs to be under `stage`. Please consult Jenkins documentation at https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/

Comment: @MaratC that's exactly my point. The solution you proposed can't work unless I put a single top level stage()

Comment: @MaratC  The picture in the docs assumes that the build and deploy are equal and the split is at run tests. I don't have that. I have two completely separated pipelines, one for windows and one for linux. The problem is that when the windows fails, the linux also stops.

Comment: Your original question quotes one pipeline, not two. You can modify your pipeline to run two stages in parallel, one "windows" and one "linux". Each stage will, first, "bootstrap", and second, "devenv". You can put "try..catch" inside if you want to gracefully handle failure.

Comment: @MaratC my original question refers to one *Jenkins* pipeline describing two *colloquial* pipelines.

Comment: It's not the terms that are used in Jenkins. In Jenkins parlance, what you have is one pipeline with two parallel stages. If any of these two fails, the whole pipeline fails. As mentioned, you may use try..catch if you want to catch some issue and prevent one of the two parallel stages from failing the entire pipeline.